# Using wait.for with nodejs and mongoskin to avoid callback hell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoskin

I m actually developping a little application with mongodb and nodejs to create my REST Api.
I face a problem when I need to access an object reference :

- I have a roadmap collection which reference a user object
- When I want to get all the roadmaps, I have to loop on my roadmap array to lazy load my users, by the ref ID stored in the roadmap collection
- I have a callback problem, the user is not loaded when I need it

I have found a solution using Wait.for library : https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor , but I dont know how it works. I tried everything, but no way to make it work

```
all: (req,res)->
    @em.collection(@collection).find().toArray((err, result)=>
      roadmaps = []
      for r in result
        r.user = @getUser(r.user.oid)
        roadmaps.push r
      res.send(roadmaps))



 getUser: (oid)->
    @em.collection('user').findOne {_id: new @objectId(oid)}, (err, res)=>
      if !err
        return res
      return undefined
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to make it works properly ? Where should I put the wait.lauchFiber ? where should I put the wait.for ?

Thanks for all

Comment: you put the launchFiber when a request arrives, to handle it in a fiber. You put the wait.for at any standard async function, to wait for its result. you'll need to code a wrapper if the callback is not the standard `callback(err,data)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript, please correct me and I'll edit this answer.

```
all: (req,res)->
    var result = wait.forMethod(@em.collection(@collection).find(), "toArray")
    roadmaps = []
    for r in result
        r.user = @getUser(r.user.oid)
        roadmaps.push r
    res.send(roadmaps)



 getUser: (oid)->
    try
      return wait.forMethod(@em.collection('user'),"findOne",{_id:new @objectId(oid)})
    catch(err)
      return undefined
```

As you can see, for "getUser", if the method is that simple, you better use your version, with the callback.

#### "where to put the launchFiber()?"

you put the launchFiber when a request arrives. see https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor#proper-use